# greek letters in colab notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter, google-colaboratory

In a garden variety Jupyter notebook code cell, typing \alpha results in the greek letter alpha. However, when you do this in a `colab` notebook this works intermittently at best. Is there a trick? Is this a known bug?

Comment: I prefer to install the Greek keyboard and type Greek letters directly. Obviously

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos for those of us not using greek for most things, I wonder if there is a way to (somewhat) seamlessly change between greek and US keyboards...

Comment: You can add multiple keyboards in any OS in about 1 minute and switch between languages using either a keyboard shortcut or a taskbar icon. That's faster than trying to type Alt+224 or opening the OS's keyboard map. Now that the kids learn German and French at school I have *4* keyboards installed

Comment: The real problem is that a math symbol that looks like α or more likely Σ is actually an operator, not a letter. In ∑Σ the first letter is the Unicode Sum symbol, the second is the Greek letter. And neither is a `\sum`, they're just glyphs. An equation with the proper operators can be executed, using letters isn't executable.  `\alpha` isn't α in an equation. How each appears depends on the font. If Colab Notebook can't handle symbols, yes, it's a bug. If it affects execution it's a serious bug. Even if it only affects display it's still a bug, just not as serious